# Include file not accessible in classic asp IIS 7.5 Windows Web Server 2008 R2

Tags: asp-classic, iis-7.5, windows-server-2008-x64

I am trying to run asp app with IIS 7.5 in Windows WebServer 2008 R2.
I am getting the following error

> Active Server Pages error 'ASP 0126'
>
> Include file not found
>
> /VD/default.asp, line 2
>
> The include file '/inc/abc.asp' was not found.

I am using the following tag to include

```
<!-- #include virtual="/inc/abc.asp" -->
```

I also tried enabling the parent path and using the file="..\inc\abc.asp"

I have also created a new app pool for classic asp with
.Net Version = No Managed Code
Managed Pipeline Mode = classic

Still not able to include asp file

Answer (score 0):

I was using default web site and created Virtual Directory under that site.
The default web site was pointing to c:\inetpub\wwwroot
The VD was pointing to  totally different path eg C:\Myproj\Web

Some how the virtual in the below line was pointing c:\inetpub\wwwroot and not C:\Myproj\Web
[include virtual="/inc/abc.asp"]

hence it was not finding the inc folder.

I removed the virtual directory and used only the site..and give the site path as C:\Myproj\Web.

Regards
Ameet